# How to use recursion in Risc-V ? To translate c into Risc-V

Tags: c, assembly, riscv, riscv32

We have an assignment to translate the following C code to assembly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int ret;
    while (a != b){
        if (a > b){
             ret = gcd(a - b, b);
             return ret;
        }
        else{
            ret = gcd(a , b - a);
             return ret;
        }
    }
    return a;
}

void main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
    
    printf("a & b? ");
    scanf(" %d %d",&a,&b );
    
    c = gcd(a, b);
    printf("result = %d",c);
}
```

Which finds the greatest common divisor of an integer.
We must translate it to assembly

```
.data
str1:    .ascii "result = \0"
str2:    .ascii "\n\0"

.text

.global main

main:
    addi sp,sp,-32 
    sw  ra,28(sp)
    sw  s0,24(sp)
    addi s0,sp,32
    call read_int
    mv s0,a0    
    call read_int
    mv s1,a0    
    mv a0,s0    #a0 = a
    mv a1,s1    #a1 = b
    call gcd
    mv s1,a0
    la a0,str1
    call print_string
    mv a0,s1
    call print_int
    la a0,str2
    call print_string
    lw  ra,28(sp)
    lw  s0,24(sp)
    addi    sp,sp,32
    call show_pc
    call exit
    ret

gcd:
    addi sp,sp,-8   # Increase stack w/ space for 1 int
    sw s3,4(sp)     # push S0 to stack
    sw s4,4(sp)
L1: beq a0,a1,L2    # if (a0==a1) go to L2
    slt s4,a0,a1    # if (a<b) s1=1, else s4=0
    beq s4,zero,L3  # if s4==0 go to L3
    sub s3,a0,a1    # varRet(s3) = a-b
    call gcd        # recursion
L3: sub s3,a1,a0    # varRet(s3) = b-a
    call gcd        # recursion
    beq zero,zero,L1 # jump to L1
L2: lw s3,4(sp)     # restore old s0
    lw s4,4(sp)
    addi sp,sp,4    # decrease stack
    jr ra           # jump to ra
```

But I am getting a data saving error in my code in my gcd function. Probably because how I am using the variables or ending the function.

Any help on understanding how to do that would be appreciated.

Comment: From a quick glance, you subtract 8 from `sp` but only add back `4`. Also you seem to use the same stack slot for `s3` and `s4` (and the comment is misleadingly talking about `s0`). Furthermore you don't preserve `ra`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Erik's answer explains what is wrong with the code. There are a number of errors. I'll list a few:

1. register save/restore code is wrong. Both store/load from `4(sp)` so one register is clobbered
2. Wrong `addi` in restore code--it does not match the save code
3. No save/restore of the return address (e.g. `ra`). Actually, this is the *only* register that needs save/restore.
4. `a0/a1` (i.e. `a` and `b`) are never changed for the recursive call
5. Usually, the return value is in `v0`. That's just the convention so not so big a deal.
6. We only need one extra register to take the `slt` result. By convention, this can be a `t*` register [which doesn't need save/restore].

Note that in the code below, I've tested the modified C functions but not the asm.

---

When I want to write assembler, I rewrite the C code to use just `if` and `goto` to more closely mimic the [proposed] assembler.

The `if` can only be simple (e.g.) `if (a > b)` and *not* `if ((a > b) && (c < d))`. The latter must be split into simple `if` (using more `goto`)

```
int
gcd3(int a, int b)
{
    int ret = a;

    if (a == b)
        goto done;

    if (a > b)
        goto a_gt_b;

a_lt_b:
        ret = gcd(a, b - a);
        goto done;

a_gt_b:
        ret = gcd(a - b, b);
        goto done;

done:
    return ret;
}
```

Here is the refactored asm code:

```
gcd:
    addi    sp,sp,-4                # Increase stack w/ space for 1 int
    sw      ra,0(sp)                # save return address

    add     v0,a0,zero              # ret = a

    beq     a0,a1,done              # if (a == b) we are done

    slt     t0,a0,a1                # is a > b?
    beq     t0,zero,a_gt_b          # yes, fly

    # a < b
a_lt_b:
    sub     a1,a1,a0                # b = b - a
    call    gcd                     # recursion
    b       done

    # a > b
a_gt_b:
    sub     a0,a0,a1                # a = a - b
    call    gcd                     # recursion
    b       done

done:
    lw      ra,0(sp)                # restore return address
    addi    sp,sp,4                 # decrease stack
    jr      ra                      # return
```

---

Your original C code combined elements of recursion and looping. The function doesn't really need to be recursive at all.

Here's a looping version:

```
int
gcd4(int a, int b)
{

loop:
    if (a == b)
        goto done;

    if (a > b)
        goto a_gt_b;

a_lt_b:
    b = b - a;
    goto loop;

a_gt_b:
    a = a - b;
    goto loop;

done:
    return a;
}
```

Here is the assembler code:

```
gcd:
    beq     a0,a1,done              # if (a == b) we are done

    slt     t0,a0,a1                # is a > b?
    beq     t0,zero,a_gt_b          # yes, fly

    # a < b
a_lt_b:
    sub     a1,a1,a0                # b = b - a
    b       gcd

    # a > b
a_gt_b:
    sub     a0,a0,a1                # a = a - b
    b       gcd

done:
    add     v0,a0,zero              # ret = a
    jr      ra                      # return
```

---

Here's the full test C program that I used:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
gcd(int a, int b)
{
    int ret;

    while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) {
            ret = gcd(a - b, b);
            return ret;
        }
        else {
            ret = gcd(a, b - a);
            return ret;
        }
    }

    return a;
}

int
gcd2(int a, int b)
{
    int ret = a;

    while (a != b) {
        if (a > b) {
            ret = gcd(a - b, b);
            break;
        }
        else {
            ret = gcd(a, b - a);
            break;
        }
    }

    return ret;
}

int
gcd3(int a, int b)
{
    int ret = a;

    if (a == b)
        goto done;

    if (a > b)
        goto a_gt_b;

a_lt_b:
        ret = gcd(a, b - a);
        goto done;

a_gt_b:
        ret = gcd(a - b, b);
        goto done;

done:
    return ret;
}

int
gcd4(int a, int b)
{

loop:
    if (a == b)
        goto done;

    if (a > b)
        goto a_gt_b;

a_lt_b:
    b = b - a;
    goto loop;

a_gt_b:
    a = a - b;
    goto loop;

done:
    return a;
}

int
main(void)
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int code = 0;
    char buf[100];

    while (1) {
        printf("a & b? ");
        fflush(stdout);

        if (fgets(buf,sizeof(buf),stdin) == NULL)
            break;
        if (buf[0] == '\n')
            break;

        sscanf(buf," %d %d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d %d\n", a, b);

        int c1 = gcd(a, b);
        printf("gcd1 = %d\n", c1);

        int c3 = gcd3(a, b);
        printf("gcd3 = %d\n", c3);
        if (c3 != c1) {
            printf("MISMATCH\n");
            code = 1;
        }

        int c4 = gcd4(a, b);
        printf("gcd4 = %d\n", c4);
        if (c4 != c1) {
            printf("MISMATCH\n");
            code = 1;
        }

        if (code)
            break;
    }

    return code;
}
```

Comment: "Usually, the return value is in v0. That's just the convention so not so big a deal."  It does depends on the coursework & instruction whether it is a deal or not, though let's note that the apparently-given `main` expects `gcd`'s return value in `a0`..  (There's no v0 in RISC V, so return values go in a0.)

Answer (score 2):

Recursion is a bit of a [red herring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_herring).  As long as the runtime architecture supports a (recursive) call stack — RISC V environments do — then supporting or doing recursion comes down to the same thing as a function, A, calling another function, B.  (In the recursive case, A and B are the same function.)  The point being that all you have to do is follow the rules for *function calling* and recursion will simply work.

(There are opportunities for optimizing function calling by deviating from the standard calling rules, but that's generally not what instructors are going for here.)

I would address the following:

- Using registers `s3` & `s4`, which are unnecessary for this function.  (If you do use them, need to fix prologue and epilog as both `s3` and `s4` are being saved to the same exact memory location, so last to be saved wins the memory location.)
- Should use call-clobbered register for `ret`, i.e. `a0` is a good choice there.
- Consider using maybe `t0` for your temps involving the relational test, but that is a MIPS style of programming: unlike MIPS, RISC V has the full complement of relations in conditional branches, so an `slt` is not required.
- Must properly pass (`a-b`,`b`) as parameters to recursive call, first arg in `a0`, second in `a1`.  Same for passing (`a`,`b-a`) in the second call.
- Should allocate stack space and preserve `ra` as it will automatically be repurposed for subsequent calling and you'll need the original `ra` value to get back to the proper caller.
- The control flow of the assembly doesn't match the C code.  Though the C code is written using a `while` loop, it actually contains no looping.  Every path inside the loop body has a `return` statement, thus, the "loop" runs either never or just once — would be better written as an `if`.  The assembly code attempts to make an actual loop, missing the point of `return` statements on all the code paths in the loop.  The `return` construct needs to execute function epilog (and return to the caller) rather than falling through to some random part of code that happens to be next.

Comment: Note that in the save/restore for `s3/s4`, they both use the same offset: `4(sp)` so one gets trashed. Also, the save uses: `addi sp,sp,-8` but the restore uses: `addi sp,sp,4` And, `a0` and `a1` are never changed for the recursive calls, so they only use the _original_ `a` and `b` values

Comment: @CraigEstey, yes, that's why I said that for saving the regs to the exact same memory location, last one wins.  I didn't address the imbalanced stack allocate/deallocate since (a) Jester already pointed it out, and (b) there's no point in saving s3 & s4 anyway, and the code must save/restore ra, so a bit of rewrite needed there for multiple reasons.  a0 and a1 need to be used properly to pass parameters to the subsequent calls or else the code won't run the same as the C -- always a bad idea to attempt optimizing the algorithm in translation to assembly, if that's what the OP was trying.

Comment: There's even more issues. AFAICT, there's no need for a loop in the recursive function!? In the C code, the `while` can/should be `if`!?

Comment: @CraigEstey, I agree and was just adding that to the answer.